# Java creating zip file with the contents of the entire folder structure

Tags: java, zip

I am having problems creating a zip file, that contains files outside the project structure (for example: C:/folder/subfolder). What happens is that the zip file will contain the entire folder structure the files are placed in.
Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("f:/arhiva.zip");
          ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

          String file1Name = "c:/zer/HOTTT.pdf";
          String file2Name = "c:/zer/fisx.docx";
          String file3Name = "c:/zer/fisx.xlsx";

          addToZipFile(file1Name, zos);
          addToZipFile(file2Name, zos);
          addToZipFile(file3Name, zos);

          zos.close();
          fos.close();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }


    public static void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

          System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

          File file = new File(fileName);
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
          ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
          zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

          byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
          int length;
          while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
              zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
          }

          zos.closeEntry();
          fis.close();
      }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It appears that using Path solves the problem.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("f:/arhivaB.zip");
          ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

          Path calea = Paths.get("c:\\bin\\HOTTT.pdf");
          File fisa = calea.toFile();
          Path caleb = Paths.get("c:\\bin\\fisx.docx");
          File fisb = caleb.toFile();
          Path calec = Paths.get("c:\\bin\\fisx.xlsx");
          File fisc = calec.toFile();


          addToZipFile(fisa, zos);
          addToZipFile(fisb, zos);
          addToZipFile(fisc, zos);
//          addToZipFile(file1Name, zos);
//          addToZipFile(file2Name, zos);
//          addToZipFile(file3Name, zos);

          zos.close();
          fos.close();

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public static void addToZipFile(/*String fileName*/ File fisa, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

//      System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

//      File file = new File(fileName);
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fisa);
      ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fisa.getName());
      zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
      int length;
      while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
          zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
      }

      zos.closeEntry();
      fis.close();
  }
```